# How to increase ag-grid drawing performance

Tags: ag-grid

ag-grid-enterprise v20.2.0.
Chrome v73.

I have several columns and a large data set with a full-screen grid. I don't have any custom renders and I'm using `batchUpdateRowData()` to add to the grid.

When my app loads, I load a history of up-to 20000 records. Each time the grid draws it takes ~150ms (as per the console).

Are there any suggestions for improving the draw performance...or am I expecting too much? Due to the amount of data being loaded at start, each draw is a full re-draw of grid.

Unfortunately I cannot avoid loading these records.

Extra info:
The reason why there is a redraw is because my grid is sorted by timestamp descending and the history is loaded oldest to newest. It's loaded from a persistent topic, so has to be loaded in that order annoyingly.

Answer (score 0):

1) Given that you are loading 20000 rows, your biggest issue would be Ag-Grid trying to load and display all 20000 of them when your component starts up. You should use [infinite scrolling](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/), which displays only a fixed amount of rows on your viewport/Ag-grid table, and dynamically removing the 'hidden' ones loading the rest while you scroll along the grid. In short, you have to set the `rowModelType` property to `infinite`.

2) This point is regarding your [row buffers](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-performance/#5-configure-row-buffer), and it has a similar concept as the point above.

3) Another alternative to doing infinite scrolling is to use server-side pagination, whereby you only fetch x-number of rows for that given page, and fetch more as you scroll down/to the next page.

4) If possible, try not to disable [suppressColumnVirtualization](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/#scrolling), as the original settings for can have a slight improvement on performance since the non-visible columns are rendered until it is scrolled to.

Comment: 1) `to load and display all 20000 of them when your component starts up` , actually not. It doesn't matter what type of model you are using, `ag-grid` will display the only visible count of rows, others would be hidden.

Comment: @un.spike Oh really? I didn't know. I always thought we have to manually switch to infinite scrolling for that to work. My 'hidden', do you literally mean the CSS property whereby the DOM elements are hidden? Or do you actually mean destroying the nodes from the DOM itself?

Comment: it wouldn't appears in DOM while it shouldn't be visible