# Ag-grid-angular How to improve table performance？

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When I use JSON data to render a table, each cell is custom rendered. When there are many columns or rows in the table, the table rendering stalls. Do you have any optimization suggestions? Or not limited to cellRender, any other suggestions that can help improve table performance are acceptable. Thank you.

Expected to improve the rendering performance of ag grid annual

Comment: Hy, welcome to stack overflow, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55463115/how-to-increase-ag-grid-drawing-performance) answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

The info in the page linked to in [Daxelarne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19835740/daxelarne)'s comment has some good info, but isn't extremely coherent, so here's some more succinct suggestions.

If you are using a custom cell renderer on many columns, that overhead might be the problem, especially if you are using component renderers.

Cell formatters have the least overhead - try to use those if possible.

Slightly more complex, and with a bit more overhead is cell renderers that are functions - still pretty lightweight.

In both cases, you need to keep the formatting/rendering function as lightweight as possible - if you do a lot of work there, then obviously it's going to be slow with a lot of cells to render.
Try to use pure functions as renderers if at all possible. Having many rows shouldn't affect rendering performance, unless you've made your rowBuffer very large or turned off column optimization

The most heavyweight is a Component renderer - because the renderer will get created and destroyed for each rendered cell - the instance is not AFAIK, re-used. Try not to do this when there are many cells to render.

As far as the number of rows and columns, if you are using the client-side row model, the default is to virtualize both rows and columns, by keeping only displayable cells in the DOM.

Control of column virtualization is an on/off thing - you are either virtualizing columns or not. By default, column virtualization is on.
Make sure that you haven't turned it off by setting `suppressColumnVirtualisation` to true.

Row virtualization on by default, but can be turned off by setting  `suppressRowVirtualisation` to true.

With row virtualization on, you can control how many rows are kept in the DOM at any one time by setting the size of the 'row buffer' with the `rowBuffer` setting

So, make sure that row virtualization on, and that the row buffer is as small as you can make it while still being able to display a "page full" of rows, plus a few more (i.e. as small as possible, and still working).